# Why could the early afternoon sky be pale yellow?

Tags: scattering, atmospheric-science

The sky at my home is very misty today, nothing special about that for a winter day. But the sky's color is unusually yellow, while it normally looks plain white. It is about 2 PM here, so definitely too early for sunset phenomena.

Comparing it with a "neutral white" LED lamp spec'd at 5000 K, I would estimate the equivalent color temperature of the sky today to about 4500 K. I live in very rural area, so no chance for any significant industrial pollution.

As far as I remember, during the Europe 1999 solar eclipse, the sky looked the same (it was misty then too). But if that is similar, then why does shading the sun change its color at all? The moon has no atmosphere... Or was it just a perceptual illusion caused by the discrepancy between usual light intensity and color (so my brain tuned the color because it "expected" light that dim to be yellowish)?

I know that Raleigh scattering causes the blue sky, and vice versa the forward scattering amplitude causes the yellow-orange sunset. If that were also the reason for the noon sky's color today, I wonder why I don't always see this on every misty day.

Or could it be some unusual natural pollutant (like they sometimes say in the media, sahara dust could cause it or something)? Is there any chance to find out, or are the possible causes just too numerous?

**Edit:** I have confirmed the 4500 K with my DSLR camera (hoping that is is sufficiently accurate). Setting white balance reference to 5800 K the picture of white objects looks yellowish, with 4500 K the objects look white. So obviously no psychological effect.

Comment: A photo of the phenomena, if you have any, might help answering the question.

Comment: Do you live in an area with extreme atmospheric pollution ("smog")?

Comment: Was there a thunder storm in close temporal proximity?

Comment: @ThePhoton: see the question body. Totally rural.

Comment: @shaihorowitz: not at all, but that's what I had expected too. Maybe a storm was about to come, but finally changed its mind. ;-)

Comment: @lee: I have a decent experience in photography. Trust me, a picture wouldn't have helped. Since there haven't been any specific cloud formations, the photo would just show a homogeneous hazy sky. And the color of it would depend on the color rendition of my camera and your screen, the white balance etc.

Comment: Rural areas can have substantial pollution, for example from blowing dust after fields are tilled. Also the atmospheric conditions can matter (if you live in a valley that keeps dusty air from blowing away, for example).

Comment: @ThePhoton: ah, I didn't keep this in mind. But anyways, today the ground was rather moist, hardly a chance for dust to blow up.

Comment: @ThePhoton: usually, in the area fog gets trapped easily, although it is not a pronounced valley. Our house is even on a hill. But no ground fog at noon today (in the morning, yes). So, most probably the fog has moved to greater altitude today. But why then the yellow color which I hardly see on any other day? To be honest, I can't even rule out that this happens more often but I just don't notice it. Nonetheless, I would like to know then if this phenomenon is just similar to sunset, but at noon in the presence of dense but high-lying fog (compensating the larger travel distance at sunset).

Comment: FYI: I just saw [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Regensburg/comments/ldzdju/saharastaub/) on a German Reddit board, which seems to indicate there is dust from Africa visibly affecting the air over Europe today.

Comment: @ThePhoton: I guess that's the answer, feel free to post it as such. I actually stumbled across the Sahara dust thing while searching the web for the phenomenon, but I thought it was more of a topic during northern hemisphere summer (now: winter), so I didn't look at the dates. But I guess the search engine was more current than I expected.